# INotifyPropertyChanged: Risks with thread-safe Dispatcher implementation

Tags: c#, multithreading, inotifypropertychanged

With the implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged, I've regularly come across the typical multi-threading exception: "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it." To address this, I decided to try and implement a thread-safe OnPropertyChanged method as follows:

```
    [field: NonSerialized]
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
       {
           if (handler != null)
           {
               handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
           }
       }));                        
    }
```

What I have noted, is that there is a significant performance strain. In addition to this, are there any other risks/concerns with implementing this approach?

**EDIT**

I'm using WPF GUI technology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check if you are on the UI thread first to avoid uneccessary dispatching:

```
Dispatcher dispatcher = Dispatcher.FromThread(Thread.CurrentThread);
if (dispatcher != null) // already on UI thread, no dispatching needed
{
       if (handler != null)
       {
           handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
       }
}
else
{
   Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
   {
       if (handler != null)
       {
           handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
       }
   }));
}
```

The above snippet might need changing as you didn't specify which GUI technology you used, but you get the idea.

But if you ask me, you should choose a different approach all together and do the dispatching when you modify the properties:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    MyViewModel.MyProperty = "X");
```

Comment: Ok thanks, that makes a lot of sense. Why specifically do you prefer the second option to the first? I've got a significant amount of viewmodels in the application and would like to contain all the INotifyPropertyChanged & Dispatcher logic in one place, so that I don't have to go and find all the problematic properties (and set these using your second approach).

Comment: IMO the automatic dispatching might hide problematic code that could go without a dispatcher, you should know what runs on the UI thread and what doesn't. Bugs with threading are very hard to find, so I prefer an explicit approach. But depending on your app it might not be in issue.

Comment: A silly question, could I write `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke` in the setter of each property? Will that cause a infinite loop?

Comment: @LanYi without seeing code I can't say, unless you set properties in a circular way there won't be a loop. What will happen is that the actual setting of the property is deferred for a bit - it will be harder to debug for sure